# Java - Regular Expression valid entry

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to determine if variable `degreeOfDifficulty` a numeric value  between "1.2" and "4.8" (inclusive), and to not accept character values.  So "1.0", "4.9", "a", and "!" are invalid; "1.2", "4.8", "4.0", and "4" are valid.  Thus far I have:

```
degreeOfDiffString.matches("^[1](\\.[2-9]?)?|^[2-3](\\.[0-9]?)?|[4](\\.[0-8]?)?"))
```

Is there something I am missing that makes an error throw if I enter a character?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex when you can avoid it. You can actually parse `degreeOfDiffString` and get the numeric value (if it is numeric) and then check for upper and lower bounds (1.2 to 4.8). Easier to code and understand what is going on. Regex makes your code error prone and if you decide to change the bounds later, you have to re-work your regex.

```
try
{
    double d = Double.parseDouble(degreeOfDiffString);
    if(d >= 1.2 && d <= 4.8)
    {
        return true; // valid
    }
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex)
{
}
return false; // all other cases -> invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex for this.  Just parse your `degreeOfDiffString` using [`Double.parseDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29), and then check if the `double` is between 1.2 and 4.8 (inclusive).

Example (untested, just something I typed up now):

```
try
{
    String degreeOfDiffString = "3.4";
    double number = Double.parseDouble(degreeOfDiffString);
    if (number < 1.2 || number > 4.8) System.out.println("Invalid difficulty.");
    else
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
} catch (Exception e)
{
    // Handle exception
}
```

If there are random things in the String, such as "!" or some letter, then an [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) should be thrown, which you can deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern isn't correct as it stands.

One quibble is that you use `[1]` and `[4]` when you really mean `1` and `4` respectively.

You must put only one `^` at the start of your pattern; the other carets are incorrect. Also, Java `matches()` method matches the entire pattern against the subject so the caret is redundant.

The way you have the decimal point match phrased, it will accept both a bare period after the first digit as well as a period followed by a digit. Is this what you want?

Comment: using `[1]` or `1` is exactly the same. the brackets are redundant but don't do any harm. the additional carets are no problem either, because `|` has the lowest precedence, so the initial `^` does not apply to the second and third alternative (in fact, there is even a caret missing from the third alternative). of course you are right, if you say that `matches` uses them implicitly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try with this pattern that match accepted numbers:

```
1\\.[2-9]|[23](\\.\\d)?|4(\\.[0-7])?|4\\.8
```